# Any other optimal way to update the parent table's columns when a child table is updated?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I have a few table structure look as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    LastUpdatedBy INT,
    LastUpdatedDate DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE Info
(
    InfoID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    PersonID INT,
    Info NVARCHAR(255),
    LastUpdatedBy INT,
    LastUpdatedDate DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE Setting
(
    SettingID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    PersonID INT,
    Setting NVARCHAR(255),
    LastUpdatedBy INT,
    LastUpdatedDate DATETIME
);
```

I face a new procedure to follow that if there is any updates on Info or Setting table, I will need to do relevant updates to Person table on columns LastUpdatedBy and LastUpdatedDate.

What first come to my mind is to create a SQL trigger that automatically update Person table when Info or Setting table does. But take a quick glance through for a few articles stating that a SQL trigger should be avoided as it's an very expensive process when creating it,

While some people recommends to change in application code. For an example,

```
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    var result = db.Info.SingleOrDefault(x => x.InfoID == infoID);
    if (result != null)
    {
        result.Info = "Some new value";
        result.LastUpdatedBy = userID;
        result.LastUpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

need to change and become like this.

```
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    var result = db.Info.SingleOrDefault(x => x.InfoID == infoID);
    if (result != null)
    {
        result.Info = "Some new value";
        result.LastUpdatedBy = userID;
        result.LastUpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var person = db.Person.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PersonID == result.PersonID);
        if (person != null)
        {
            person.LastUpdatedBy = result.LastUpdatedBy;
            person.LastUpdatedDate = result.LastUpdatedDate;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

in reality, the application code is massive, a lot of code modification need to be made.

Assume there are 30+ tables, and each of them contain at least 100k of records. If creating of triggers are possible, it will be as the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName ON dbo.Info
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN 
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        UPDATE  dbo.Person
        SET     LastUpdatedBy = INSERTED.LastUpdatedBy ,
                LastUpdatedDate = INSERTED.LastUpdatedDate
        FROM    INSERTED
        WHERE   dbo.Person.PersonID = INSERTED.PersonID
    END 
GO
```

Is the SQL trigger should really be avoided in this scenario? Please explain based on your answer if can. Any alternative solution is welcome, performance first.

Comment: Trigger is fine. It is invoked once per `UPDATE` statement, even if `UPDATE` affects several rows. By the way, this is why your trigger code in the question is wrong - it will fail when several rows are updated. Once you fix the trigger code it will work just fine.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s assumed sql server due to SET NOCOUNT ON, tagged accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger is optimal (from a performance perspective) here; it's simply like running an update statement on a bunch of rows from the front end code. I don't see why you think there is a performance penalty. Your trigger code should look more like this though:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName ON dbo.Info
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE  dbo.Person
    SET     LastUpdatedBy = INSERTED.LastUpdatedBy ,
            LastUpdatedDate = INSERTED.LastUpdatedDate
    FROM    dbo.Person 
            INNER JOIN 
            INSERTED
            ON dbo.Person.PersonID = INSERTED.PersonID
END 
GO
```

There are other ways, such as making a Stored procedure that updates all tables in a transaction, or updating front end data access layer (if your front end has a lot to update, it implies it is structured wrong: one place should have responsibility for writing to this table. If your front end code has update statements peppered all through it, well.. that's a bad design) so a dedicated class maintains these two tables properly..

Right now I'd say a trigger is your easiest way out of the problem.. they aren't well liked, though not because of performance, but because they start to add confusing consequences.. imagine you as a c# developer with limited database experience, didn't know what a trigger was, and you're complaining "every time I update just this one table, all these other 27 tables change by magic! What's going on? Am I going crazy or what?" - triggers break rules like "keep all your data updating code in one place" and this is why people who engineer systems where specific parts have specific jobs, don't like them